# todos los permisos denegados en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

por error escribi `chomd`-R ugo-rwx / , como hago para solucionarlo  ?  ahora ya no puedo ni ver , ni modificar  de ninguna carpetaca. no puedo hacer absolutamente nada.

Comment: me da que te va a tocar instalar de nuevo y suponer que has perdido todo...

Comment: Si necesitas rescatar algunos archivos puedes usar `sudo chmod -R 777 /`. Si embargo el sistema necesita permisos específicos en ciertos archivos para lo cual lo más razonable es reinstalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un sistema de rescate, como [este](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) y monta tu partición. Luego ponle permisos a tus carpetas. En el caso de las carpetas de los usuarios usa su UID. Por ejemplo, el primer usuario en Ubuntu es el 1000, por lo que necesitas hacer algo como esto:

```
chown -R 1000:1000 /home/usuario
```

#### No necesitas reinstalar.